# Windows one-click image converter/optimizer

Tags: windows, images, image-processing

Looking for a Windows software that lets you

- convert images from PNG to JPG or vice-versa
- optimize images, there's several algorithms out there for this, like
- reducing size by reducing the JPEG quality from 100 to ~80 or something
- reduce resolution
- right click on image to bring up the tasks dialog
- bulk operation on multiple images

If it's Freeware, awesome, but paid will do too.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) calls from the command line can:

- Convert images between a lot of different formats
- Optimize to a given luminance and chromanance separately e.g. `convert -quality 80,80 somepict.jpg somepict80.jpg`
- Reduce size e.g. 'convert "somepict.jpg[100x100]" small.jpg` will resize to a max of 100 pixels.
- Right click: no it is a command line tool
- bulk operations - yes.

**Free** - Yes and cross platform.

Comment: You could make a script for Image Magick, and add it to the "Send to" menu in Windows. Then you can just right click on an image to run it. eg http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/08/09/useful-imagemagick-and-ffmpeg-shortcuts-for-win-sendto-menu/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the particular imag-size optimizations will be available out of the box - but for fast, user friendly, image transformation using a Graphical Interface, a nice, if obscure, tool is "photobatch" (or "phatch").

It allows you to put together a pipeline of operaiotions (like resize, rotate, change format) and apply that to whole folders at once.  Not sure how well it can be fine tuned to work on a single image from the file navigator.

Ah, I just saw your final requirement for "cross platform" - so I think it is right on.

Home: http://photobatch.stani.be/

Docs: http://photobatch.wikidot.com/